# Adding time to datetime field

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe column which contain date and time in the format 01Jan2019:10:36:46. I want to add a time column with this, which is in format 00:52:06.  The date also should incremented if the time after addition becomes greater than 24 hours.
Could someone please help me as i am a newbie to python

Comment: refer [How to create minimal, complete and verifible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Convert columns [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and sum them:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['01Jan2019:10:36:46','01Jan2019:10:36:46'], 
                   'time': ['00:52:06','20:52:06']})

print (df)
                 date      time
0  01Jan2019:10:36:46  00:52:06
1  01Jan2019:10:36:46  20:52:06

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')
#if strings like in sample
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])
#if python time is necessary convert to strings
#df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].astype(str))

df['date1'] = df['date'] + df['time']
print (df)
                 date     time               date1
0 2019-01-01 10:36:46 00:52:06 2019-01-01 11:28:52
1 2019-01-01 10:36:46 20:52:06 2019-01-02 07:28:52
```